# Retrieve record using Dynamic SQL in Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server

Currently, the parameter `EmpNo` is used to get `emmployeeno`. I am trying to use the same parameter `EmpNo` to retrieve `employeeno` or `alternateref`.

How can I can get the `alternateref` from this parameter

```
Sorry this has to be deleted due to personal information.
```

Comment: Don't object your values! If you *need* to use dynamic SQL parametrise it (using `sp_executesql`) and **properly** quote your dynamic object names using `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: Also, if you need to pass multiple values, use a table type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any difference in your two `exec` commands

Seems the procedure required 2 fixes:

1. Add additional parameter `@IsAlternativeRef bit` that re-direct the flow either to filter `EmployeeNo` or `alternateref`
2. When it re-direct `alternateref`, the main query of `@SQL` not considered

Have a look this script which has 2 fixes:

```
 --- Declare new parameter "@IsAlternativeRef bit = 0" and make mandatory parameter, 

     If @IsAlternativeRef = 0 and @EmpNo <> ''
        set @sql = @sql +  N' AND EmployeeNo LIKE '''+@EmpNo+''''
     If (NOT @IsAlternativeRef = 0) and @EmpNoClause <> ''
        set @sql =  N' AlternateRef LIKE '''+@EmpNo+''''
```

Comment: This doesn't resolve the huge injection the OP has.

Comment: @user3687828, My bad, added `()` without considering single quotes. However, updated the post, pls try now. in-case any error, i would suggest to add `print @sql` in every stage so that we could see the the syntax as it gradually formatting.

Comment: @user3687828, have you tried to exec this `exec procPayslipViewerGetEmployees @EmpNoClause=N'123566',@EmpNameClause=N'',@NIClause=N'',@PayrollClause=N'*',@PayGrpKeyClause=N'*',@DeptKeyClause=N'*',@ClassKeyClause=N'*',@CatKeyClause=N'*',@CCKeyClause=N'*',@CCFacetKey1Clause=N'*',@CCFacetKey2Clause=N'*',@CCFacetKey3Clause=N'*',@CCFacetKey4Clause=N'*',@CCFacetKey5Clause=N'*',@CCFacetKey6Clause=N'*',  @IsAlternativeRef = 1`

Answer (score 0):

If @EmpNoClause = '' then the LIKE string is '', you need to change that.

Comment: This doesn't resolve the huge injection the OP has.